# How to convert the result (as displayed) in the cell to text in Excel

Tags: excel, type-conversion

I have formatted a cell in Excel as Scientific with 1 decimal place then I inserted a number in it like (0.41). After pressing enter the result displayed is (4.1E-01). My aim is to put this result in a cell with text format so that when I double click the cell, I can copy/modify the text (4.1E-01) as I want.

I tried to format that cell as text but the result gets back to 0.41. I also tried to copy the cell and paste the value only using "Special Paste" into a text-formatted cell but the result keeps returning to 0.41. Do you have a suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a work around unless you want to use VBA.  In an adjacent cell type this formula:

```
=TEXT(A1,"0.00E+00")
```

Now you can copy that cell and paste values only and get just the text:

```
2.22E+27
```

---

If your okay with VBA use this:

```
Range("A2").Value = Range("A1").Text
```

Comment: WoW, thank you so much. This is a very simple method and yet it effectively reduced my working time on a huge data sheet. I am thinking of learning VBA too.